# Авторизация между доменом и субдоменом

Tags: php, cookie, сессия, auth

Пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию между моб. и десктоп версиями сайта. Суть вопроса:

есть моб версия по адресу m.domain.com
а также есть десктоп версия domain.com

Мне необходимо настроить авторизацию. Честно говоря я не совсем бывалый в этом вопросе, поэтому хочу попросить помочь разобраться.

Есть файл auth.php в котором происходит создание сессии, либо получение id пользователя для дальнейшей работы в сайте. Вот код:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["isauth"]) && $_SESSION["isauth"] == true)
{
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$_SESSION[uid]'");
  $user = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
else
  $user = 0;
```

Как вы успели заметить вверху я настроил создание сессии для .domain.com

Далее в десктоп версии сайта есть файл login.php который проверяет данные и собственно авторизирует пользователя:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["isauth"] = true;                         
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");
$uid = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION["uid"]=$uid[0];
```

После логинизации я могу работать с данными юзера в десктоп версии, а также могу работать и в мобильной версии, так как сессия видна для домена и субдомена

Вопрос в том, как задействовать тот же файл login.php но от десктоп версии для мобильной?.

У меня получается так, пользователь заходит на сайт m.domain.com, в файле auth.php автоматически создается сессия для всего домена и субдомена, далее идет запрос в файл login.php путем ajax, у меня там все настроено, т.е. crossdomain и тд, но почему то в самом файле не происходит запись в $_SESSION[isauth]! так как после авторизации ни в десктоп ни в мобильной версии сайта $_SESSION[isauth] по прежнему пуст.

Comment: как вы определяете что запись не происходит )

Comment: echo $_SESSION['isauth']; возвращает false, хотя если делать авторизацию на десктоп версии то будет true, а файл логинизации один!

Comment: echo не может false вывести

Comment: Простите не совсем понимаю что вы здесь делаете? здесь вопрос не про то что выводится на экране, здесь вполне конкретная ситуация. и возвращать и выводить это разные вещи. имелось введу значение.